# Difference between q.alt Parameter of eDismax and main query parameter q in solr?

Tags: solr, solrcloud, edismax

What is q.alt Parameter of eDisMax and how it is differ from main query parameter q.I go through some article but not find clear difference between them. Anyone can explain difference between them and some case in which q.alt parameter use or main query parameter q will be best.

Answer (score 1):

q.alt is used to specify the alternate query when q is absent.

you can use append &debugQuery=on&defType=edismax in your solr url to see the behaviour and understand how the queries are formed when you pass q or q.alt or both.